# How to define methods to deal with Datasets with parametrized types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to define some functions that take `Dataset`s (typed `DataFrame`s) as input and produces another as output, and I want them to be flexible enough to deal with parametrized types. In this example, I need a column to represent the ID of users, but it doesn't matter to my functions if that ID is an Int, a Long, a String, etc. That's why my case classes have this type parameter `A`.

I tried at first simply wrting my function and using `Dataset` instead of `DataFrame`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

case class InputT[A](id: A, data: Long)
case class OutputT[A](id: A, dataA: Long, dataB: Long)

def someFunction[A](ds: Dataset[InputT[A]]): Dataset[OutputT[A]] = {
  ds.select().as[OutputT[A]] // suppose there are some transformations here
}
```

... but I got this error:

```
Unable to find encoder for type OutputT[A]. An implicit Encoder[OutputT[A]] is needed
to store OutputT[A] instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and
Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support
for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

So I tried providing an Encoder for my type:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

case class InputT[A](id: A, data: Long)
case class OutputT[A](id: A, dataA: Long, dataB: Long)

implicit def enc[A]: Encoder[InputT[A]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[OutputT[A]])

def someFunction[A](ds: Dataset[InputT[A]]): Dataset[OutputT[A]] = {
  ds.select().as[OutputT[A]] // suppose there are some transformations here
}
```

And now I get this error:

```
No TypeTag available for OutputT[A]
```

If the code is the same as above, but without type parameters (e.g., using `String` instead of `A`), then there are no errors.

Avoiding the use of `import spark.implicits._` magic if possible, what should I do to fix it? Is it even possible to achieve this level of flexibility with `Dataset`?

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work :/

Comment: Worked like a charm now! Thanks. Could you post that as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [**Scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#as%5BU%5D(implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) You would see that `as` requires an `Encoder` so you only need to add it to the scope.

```scala
def someFunction[A](ds: Dataset[InputT[A]])(implicit ev: Encoder[[OutputT[A]]): Dataset[OutputT[A]] = {
  ds.select().as[OutputT[A]]
}
```

---

Also, you may want to take a look at [**Where does Scala look for implicits**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits/5598107#5598107).